# Android ViewPager activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

After some extensive research on the topic, I've reached an impasse.  I'm trying to implement the `ViewPager` from Android's '[Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)' tutorial to have different text on each page, like you are swiping through pages in a book.  The way it's set up, they have two XML files (one that implements the ViewPager element in a Fragment Activity class, one that has a textview in a Fragment class) that shows Lorem Ipsum on every single page.  I'm trying to find a way to change the textview in the Fragment class so that when I go to page 2, 3, 4, etc. there is different text on each page.

In the `ScreenSlideActivity` class, I've tried using a switch inside the `onPageScrollStateChanged(int position)` inner event handler, setting certain text views to visible/invisible.  I've also tried using a switch inside the ScreenSlidePageFragment class in the onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) method.  Is this the right approach or am I way off?  I'm definitely overlooking something, could some please point me in the right direction?

This is a build targeting APIs 14 to 17, using Eclipse.  Below please find some code from the two classes, as well as the XML file with the textview:

//Fragment Activity class //

```
public class ScreenSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {
/**
 * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
 */
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager mPager;

/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

 // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When changing pages, reset the action bar actions since they are dependent
            // on which page is currently active. An alternative approach is to have each
            // fragment expose actions itself (rather than the activity exposing actions),
            // but for simplicity, the activity provides the actions in this sample.

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

// Fragment class //

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";

/**
 * The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
 */
private int mPageNumber;

/**
 * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the given page number.
 */
public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    // Set the title view to show the page number.
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
            getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
 */
public int getPageNumber() {
    return mPageNumber;
}
```

}

// XML layout //

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Dummy content. -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lorem_ipsum1"
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code... `setText(getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1))`? The two parameter method for `getString(...)` requires an `Object` which specifies format arguments.

Comment: There is a title in a TextView at the top of the layout that lists the name of the document (Lorem Ipsum) as defined in strings.xml, and the + 1 increments the page number (Lorem Ipsum page 1, Lorem Ipsum page 2, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, I had to create a switch statement inside the `ScreenSlidePageFragment`, turning off/on the visibility (`VISIBILE` or `GONE`) depending on the `mPageNumber` variable (i.e. the page number determined the string value set for that page).  Is this a hack job, inefficient, or just fine?  Bottom line, it works.  All strings are saved in strings.xml.  Again, not sure if this is good practice for larger strings.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    // Set the title view to show the page number.
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
            getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

    switch(mPageNumber){
        case 0:
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case 1:
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case 2:
          rootView.findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
          rootView.findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
          rootView.findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          break;
        }

    return rootView;
}
```